# NSManagedObject's objectID saves to variable, but this variable has become nil when invoked from .sheet handler

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

The iOS app I'm building iterates through a list of PhraseGroup objects defined in Core Data and displays the `extraText` value associated with each PhraseGroup.

This is the top part of Xcode's generated NSManagedObject subclass for PhraseGroup:

```
extension PhraseGroup {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<PhraseGroup> {
    return NSFetchRequest<PhraseGroup>(entityName: "PhraseGroup")
}

@NSManaged public var extraText: String?
@NSManaged public var phraseGroupID: UUID
@NSManaged public var text: String?
@NSManaged public var phrase: NSSet?
@NSManaged public var piece: Piece
```

I would like users to be able to long press any extraText entry in my displayed list and then edit it in a modal sheet. However, I am struggling to find a way of passing a valid reference to the long-pressed PhraseGroup through to my sheet.

The following shows how I'm displaying a list of PhraseGroups `extraText` values:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct PhraseGroupView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
@Binding var phraseGroupViewAlertItem: AlertItem?
@State private var isEditMode: EditMode = .inactive
@State private var showingPhraseGroupEditView = false
@State private var phraseGroupObjectID: NSManagedObjectID!

private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<PhraseGroup>
private var phraseGroups: FetchedResults<PhraseGroup> { fetchRequest.wrappedValue }


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Section {
                List {
                    ForEach (phraseGroups, id: (\PhraseGroup.phraseGroupID)) { phraseGroup in
                        HStack {
                            Text("\(phraseGroup.wrappedExtraText)")
                        }
                        .onLongPressGesture {
                            phraseGroupObjectID = phraseGroup.objectID
                            showingPhraseGroupEditView = true
                            print(phraseGroup.extraText!)  // Sanity check to prove I've got hold of the right row
                            let phraseGroupForEditing = moc.object(with: phraseGroupObjectID) as! PhraseGroup
                            dump(phraseGroupForEditing)
                            print(phraseGroupForEditing.extraText!)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingPhraseGroupEditView) {
                    self.phraseGroupObjectID == nil
                        ?
                        TestPhraseGroupEditView(phraseGroupObjectID: phraseGroupObjectID, message: "phraseGroupObjectID is nil")
                        :
                        TestPhraseGroupEditView(phraseGroupObjectID: phraseGroupObjectID, message: "phraseGroupObjectID is not nil")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("This is phraseGroup navBarTitle", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                HStack {
                                    Button(action: {
                                        // yet to come
                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "plus").resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                            .foregroundColor(.myKeyColor)
                                    }
                                }, trailing:
                                    HStack {
                                        EditButton()
                                            .frame(width: 60, height: 20)
                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                            .foregroundColor(.myKeyColor)
                                    })
        .environment(\.editMode, self.$isEditMode)
    }
}
```

I am using the following init function to set up this view:

```
init (phraseGroupViewAlertItem: Binding<AlertItem?>, piece: Piece) {
    self._phraseGroupViewAlertItem = phraseGroupViewAlertItem
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<PhraseGroup>(
        entity: PhraseGroup.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: "extraText", ascending: true)
        ],
        predicate: NSPredicate(format: "piece == %@", piece)
        // 'piece' in the predicate above is the name of a Piece <- PhraseGroup relationship defined in Core Data
    )
}
```

When I long press a row in my list, I can see in my debugger, stepping through the `onLongPressGesture` closure, that I've got hold of the right PhraseGroup (that is, the one I've pressed), that I'm correctly reading that PhraseGroup's `objectID` into a @State var and then create another reference to the same Core Data object and out its `extraText` value.

However, by the time .sheet closure is presented immediately afterwards, phraseGroupObjectID has been set to nil, as I can see clearly when TestPhraseGroupEditView is displayed.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct TestPhraseGroupEditView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
var phraseGroupObjectID: NSManagedObjectID!
var message: String

var body: some View {
    VStack (spacing: 20){
        Text(message)
        Text("Tap to create phraseGroup for debugger").onTapGesture {
            dump(phraseGroupObjectID)
            let phraseGroupForEditing = moc.object(with: phraseGroupObjectID) as! PhraseGroup
            dump(phraseGroupForEditing)
        }
    }
}
}
```

The message in the first Text field reads `phraseGroupObjectID is nil`, and clicking the second Text results in the first dump() printing `-nil`, followed by `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file AK6/TestPhraseGroupEditView.swift, line 22`

What is it that I'm failing to understand here? Is there some minor glitch in my implementation I've overlooked, or am I going about this in a completely wrong-headed way? Apple have got some pretty good doco on faulting or uniquing at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html, but nothing I've read there jumps out at me as an obvious solution to my issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a Bool to toggle the sheet, you can use an optional object and pass data directly into the sheet.
Change your phaseGroupObjectID definition to the following

```
@State private var phraseGroupObjectID: NSManagedObjectID? = nil
```

Change your .onLongPressGesture to the following

```
.onLongPressGesture {
                        phraseGroupObjectID = phraseGroup.objectID
                        print(phraseGroup.extraText!)  // Sanity check to prove I've got hold of the right row
                        let phraseGroupForEditing = moc.object(with: phraseGroupObjectID) as! PhraseGroup
                        dump(phraseGroupForEditing)
                        print(phraseGroupForEditing.extraText!)
                    }
```

Change your sheet to the following

```
.sheet(item: $self.phraseGroupObjectID) { objID in
    TestPhraseGroupEditView(phraseGroupObjectID: objID, message: "phraseGroupObjectID is not nil")
 }
```

You can now remove showingPhraseGroupEditView.

The sheet gets shown whenever phaseGroupObjectID is not nil. You can dismiss the sheet by setting phaseGroupObjectID to nil again.

Comment: bravo. Had to implement `extension NSManagedObjectID: Identifiable {}` to avoid error re nonconformity to `Identifiable`. In TestPhraseGroupEditView now have `let phraseGroupForEditing = moc.registeredObject(for: phraseGroupObjectID! as NSManagedObjectID) as! PhraseGroup` to grab NSManagedObject. Changed `$self.phraseGroupObjectID` to `self.$phraseGroupObjectID`. Couldn't find a way of binding to phraseGroupObjectID in sheet so I could set it to nil and close the sheet via button, but if user dismisses sheet by dragging it down the effect is equivalent.